# Drupal Print Module - change name for PDF output

Tags: php, drupal, pdf-generation, print-module

How to change name for PDF output in PRINT module, for each module separately? Can I use a some sort of hook for it? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The Print module includes a drupal_alter function in print_pdf.page.inc

```
drupal_alter('print_pdf_filename', $pdf_filename, $path);
```

This results in the following hook being available for use:

```
function hook_print_pdf_filename_alter(&$pdf_filename, $path) {
  $pdf_filename = 'yourfilename';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could  not find a hook but I did manage to find the variable for it.

I had  a look at the module and it seems it is setting the name at line 41 page print.pdf.pages.inc.

```
$pdf_filename = variable_get('print_pdf_filename',
PRINT_PDF_FILENAME_DEFAULT);
```

So try this and put this code in your module. I am not sure if it will work

```
variable_set('print_pdf_filename', $nameouwant);
```

cheers,
Vishal